# django formset initial data not coming

Tags: django

this is my model :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, editable=False, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=TITLE_TYPES, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='Name') 
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='LastName') 
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True, verbose_name='Gender') 
    dob = models.DateField('dob')
    redressno = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='RedressNo')
```

this is my form

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):
  dob = forms.DateField(required=False, input_formats=('%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y'))
  class Meta:
    model = Member
    exclude = ('profile',)
```

this is my view :

```
     members = Member.objects.filter(profile=profiles)
data1 = serializers.serialize( "python", members)
        print data1[0]['fields']
        memarr=[] 
        for index, a in enumerate(data1):
          memarr.append(a['fields'])
        print memarr
        MemberFormSet = formset_factory(MemberForm, formset=BaseFormSet)    
        member_formset = MemberFormSet(initial=memarr)
        #here setting intial array of mem 
        mdata['form-TOTAL_FORMS']=u'2'
        mdata['form-INITIAL_FORMS']=u'0'
        mdata['form-MAX_NUM_FORMS']=u''

        member_formset = MemberFormSet(mdata)

        memberform = MemberForm(mdata)

    c = {'form': form, 'memberform': memberform, 'member_formset': member_formset}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('edit_profile.html', c, RequestContext(request))
```

m passing the initial data but still the initial data is not being shown in the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
member_formset = MemberFormSet(initial=memarr)
...
member_formset = MemberFormSet(mdata)
```

You're setting the initial data on one FormSet instance, and then throwing away that instance with the initial data and overwriting with another new FormSet instance.

You can simplify your view to this:

```
# If you are not using csrf middleware, use this decorator instead of ghetto magic
@csrf_protect
@render_to('edit_profile.html') # handy decorator from django-annoying
def profile_members_edit(request.profile):

    members = Member.objects.filter(profile=profiles)

    # iterate over the ValuesQuerySet gives a list of dicts for initial data
    member_data = list(members.values())

    # setting extra=<> and max_num=<> is easier than setting internal form data
    MemberFormSet = formset_factory(MemberForm, formset=BaseFormSet, extra=2)

    member_formset = MemberFormSet(initial=member_data)

    return {'member_formset': member_formset }
```

Comment: okay , so how will i pass the management form property in first instance

Comment: updated comment, have a look at how it should be done. Also, do you really need that extra MemberForm, or was that for debug purposes?

Comment: thanks dont need Memberform. will remove that , i tried giving extra=2 but it gives an error  

`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra'`